# Need to convert &quot &amp &lt to ", & , < in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I am trying to circumvent ADFS authentication and when i sign in to the application i get the below response from the server:

```
name="wresult" value="&lt;t:RequestSecurityTokenResponse
xmlns:t=&quot;http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust&quot;>&lt;t:Lifetime>&lt;wsu:Created
xmlns:wsu=&quot;http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd&quot;>2017-02-10T09:28:07.059Z&lt;/wsu:Created>&lt;wsu:Expires xmlns:wsu=&quot;http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd&quot;>2017-02-10T10:28:07.059Z&lt;/wsu:Expires>&lt;/t:Lifetime>&lt;wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp=&quot;http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy&quot;>&lt;wsa:EndpointReference
xmlns:wsa=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing&quot;>&lt;wsa:Address>https://gh-prem.accesscontrol.windows.net/&lt;/wsa:Address>&lt;/wsa:EndpointReference>&lt;/wsp:AppliesTo>&lt;t:RequestedSecurityToken>&lt;saml:Assertion
MajorVersion=&quot;1&quot; MinorVersion=&quot;1&quot;> AssertionID=&quot;_cb580c90-d0ac-49a8-a9c4-3ecb8b0a54d1&quot;
Issuer=&quot;http://abc.abc.dev.comt/adfs/services/trust&quot;
IssueInstant=&quot;2017-02-10T09:28:07.075Z&quot;
 xmlns:saml=&quot;urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion&quot;>&lt;saml:Conditions NotBefore=&quot;2017-02-10T09:28:07.059Z&quot;
NotOnOrAfter=&quot;2017-02-10T10:28:07.059Z&quot;>&lt;saml:AudienceRestrictionCondition>&lt;saml:Audience>https://gh-prem.accesscontrol.windows.net/&lt;/saml:Audience>&lt;/saml:AudienceRestrictionCondition>&lt;/saml:Conditions>&lt;saml:AttributeStatement>&lt;saml:Subject>&lt;saml:SubjectConfirmation>&lt;saml:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearer&lt;/saml:ConfirmationMethod>&lt;/saml:SubjectConfirmation>&lt;/saml:Subject>&lt;saml:Attribute
AttributeName=&quot;name&quot;
```

How to convert the &quot and &lt in jmeter. Since the POST body of the next sampler take the attributes as below:

```
<t:RequestSecurityTokenResponse
xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust"><t:Lifetime><wsu:Created
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">2017-02-06T10:06:14.384Z</wsu:Created><wsu:Expires
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">2017-02-06T11:06:14.384Z</wsu:Expires></t:Lifetime><wsp:AppliesTo
xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"><wsa:EndpointReference xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><wsa:Address>https://gh-prem.accesscontrol.windows.net/</wsa:Address></wsa:EndpointReference></wsp:AppliesTo><t:RequestedSecurityToken><saml:Assertion
MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="1"
AssertionID="_99273d06-e73c-4ce5-acf5-6ba43c8c7990"
Issuer="http://xxx.xxx-dev.comt/adfs/services/trust"
IssueInstant="2017-02-06T10:06:14.400Z"
xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion"><saml:Conditions
NotBefore="2017-02-06T10:06:14.384Z"
NotOnOrAfter="2017-02-06T11:06:14.384Z"><saml:AudienceRestrictionCondition><saml:Audience>https://gh-prem.accesscontrol.windows.net/</saml:Audience></saml:AudienceRestrictionCondition></saml:Conditions><saml:AttributeStatement><saml:Subject><saml:SubjectConfirmation><saml:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearer</saml:ConfirmationMethod></saml:SubjectConfirmation></saml:Subject><saml:Attribute
AttributeName="name"
AttributeNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims"><saml:AttributeValue>
```

Could you please help me in solving this issue with some screenshots
I got few tips on how to use Beanshell pre processor but its not helping me or im not sure how to implement beanshell to mitigate the issue.

Note: I am using content encoding as utf-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [__unescapeHtml() function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__unescapeHtml), it can decode HTML-encoded strings on-the-fly

[image: JMeter UnescapeHTML in action]

You can use this function directly in the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler body or wherever else.

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) posts series for more information on JMeter Functions, how they can be used, what are limitations, etc.

Comment: Dmitri T: thanks for this update, Can I use parametrized value within the function? (i tried but jmeter was throwing exceptions). The encoded HTML is coming in as a request in the previous sampler - I am trying to extract the encoded HTML using regEx and passing the same in the next sample as POST request.

'${__unescapeHtml(<html>${HTML}</html>)}'

Comment: Hi Dmitri, _unescapeHtml function did help me in extracting the wresult SAML token. Thanks a ton for your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to mitigate the issue. hope it helps for the newbees (Big thanks to Dmitri Tikhanski)

The above token is SAML 1.1 token that is generated as the response to a GET method. If your using ADFS authentication you will get a big HTML in which you will have - WA, Wresult, Wctx. (for me only wresult(SAML 1.1 token) which was a correlation candidate)

Extract the wresult as following using RegularExpression Extractor.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeB49.jpg)

and the captured Wresult to be replaced in /v2/wsfederation with the function __unescapeHtml.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqgGe.jpg)

Note: 1) Wa result in my case its not dynamic
      2) wctx string is a static string.

Hope this helps. thanks.